# Is it possible to add widgets to a gridlayout in kivy from bottom to top instead of from top to bottom

Tags: python, kivy

I'm trying to add widgets to a gridlayout from bottom to top in other to minimize the time a user would take to see his or her messages on my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do add_widget like:

```
self.add_widget(new_message, index=len(self.children))
```

The new_message Widget will appear in the first location of the GridLayout (self in this case).